# Why does this N-channel MOSFET not turn off?

Tags: circuit-protection, nmos, over-voltage-protection

I was playing around on CircuitLab to see if I can add an overvoltage cutoff to the reverse voltage protection circuit in [TIs slva139](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva139/slva139.pdf?ts=1587990452696). Using a zener, I expect OVS to start rising beyond the zener voltage and turn on Q1, and pull PGD to ground. This happens fine. However, M1 does not seem to be turning off, even with PGD < Vn.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffmETO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Circuitlab Simulation results for DC sweep (-15-+15):

[image: Circuitlab Simulation results for DC sweep]

I suspect I'm missing something incredibly stupid, but I can't figure out what. Help would be appreciated, as well on comments about why this is a stupid protection circuit (which I suspect it is, because it seems trivial and yet never used).

For context, I'm only attempting to protect against, say, insertion of 12V in a 5V input, which might fry 5V components connected to the rail.

Comment: For overvoltage cutoff, the MOSFET is reversed. Q1 controls Vgd when it should control Vgs. Then as Vn goes positive the body diode conducts. There's a reason why power switches that have to isolate bidirectional power use 2 MOSFETs...

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks. I forgot about the body diode. If you put that in as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4):

There is a parasitic diode in your MOSFET (aka the body diode) that will keep your output current flowing irrespective of how you believe you are controlling the device: -

[image]

Maybe you meant the MOSFET source and drain to be swapped but screwed-up?